# How does Partials / Template inheritance work in Mustache?

Tags: javascript, mustache, hogan.js

I don't really understand partials / template inheritance from Mustache / Hogan.js. As defined [here](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) and [here](https://github.com/mustache/spec/pull/75) you seem to must have two different files to make that work. I use it as follows in my (client side) page:

`<template id="server-template">
        {{#servers}}
        <b>some html and {{> some other which I dont understand how to use}}</b>
        {{/servers}}
</template>
<template id="room-template">
        I want this in up there. (in the "partials" tag)
</template>`

Thanks for helping. I compile them with this:

`var source = $('#room-template').html(),
 compiled = Hogan.compile(source)
 $('#main').html(compiled.render(data))`

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#partials) state that you must compile your partials separately, and then pass them to the `render` function:

> In mustache.js an object of partials may be passed as the third
>   argument to Mustache.render. The object should be keyed by the name of
>   the partial, and its value should be the partial text.

```
var roomTemplateSource = $('#room-template').html();
var roomTemplate = Mustache.compile(roomTemplateSource);
Mustache.render(template, view, {
  room: roomTemplate
});

<template id="server-template">
        {{#servers}}
        <b>some html and {{> room}}</b>
        {{/servers}}
</template>
```